# Implement presenter view QT application

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4

I'm trying to write a QT4 application that needs to have a Presenter View, something like Powerpoint does:

http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/en-us/files/636/030/ZA010212681.gif

Any thoughts on can I do this? It's possible?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Also, explain why you think this presenter view could not be done in Qt? Why do you have concerns? In addition, please prefer inline images, although the one in question is a bad one since it does not show the view very close.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still learning C++ with QT, I've found this: qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Qt supports both multiple screens and frameless full-screen windows, so you can certainly have a presenter window on one screen, and the beamed window on another screen. So yes, it is possible, and it's easy in fact.

Comment: Hello! Thank you! Can you point me to some example/tutorial? I'm sorry, I'm really a noob at qt framework.